# Output Cygwin/bash results to text file

Tags: bash, batch-file, cygwin, dos

I'm writing a script that will run from the Task Scheduler. It's not executing correctly from the Scheduler, but will execute correctly from the command line.  (Possibly a permissions issue?)  I wanted to redirect the output to a text file, but I'm getting an empty `results.txt` file when executed from either the command line or the Scheduler.

This is the content of the batch file:

```
D:
chdir D:\scripts
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i D:\scripts\myscript.sh > results.txt
```

Comment: there is 'select all' option with cygwin. just copy paste it

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maybe your script writes to the standard error (`stderr`). Try changing

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i D:\scripts\myscript.sh > results.txt
```

to

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i D:\scripts\myscript.sh > results.txt  2>&1
```

It's redirects `stderr` too to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try a UNIX style file path:

```
C:\cygwin\bin\bash --login -i /cygdrive/d/scripts/myscript.sh > results.txt
```